# For the following sequence, how do I find if it converges and if so how do I find its limits.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

For the following sequence, how do I find if it converges and if so how do I find its limits.

$$a_n = \frac{12−8n}{4n+36},  (n=1,2,3,...)$$

What are the steps that I need to follow to get the answer?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Divide numerator and denominator by $n$. Then check what the limit is as $ n$ tends to $\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities to solve this problem.

One was already mentioned by lsp.

Divide numerator and denominator by n (the limit should stay the same) and check wath happens when $n$ goes to infinity. Remember ($\frac{a}{n} \to 0$ when $n \to \infty$)

You dan also see the limit as the asymptotic limit of two continuous functions (make the $n$ continuous instead of discrete. This subsequence should converge to the same limit.) With de l'Hospital:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{12-8n}{4n+36} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{-8}{4} = -2
$$